# Creating clusters of objects from an array ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

from the code below I am trying to create objects out of an array and then stratify the objects into clusters by referencing their index positions.

```
 $array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

 class Stuff
   attr_accessor :object_name
   def initialize(x)
     @x = x
   end
   def object_name
     "object #{@x}"
   end
 end

 def number(i)
   n = $array.index(i)
   n += 1
 end

 puts $array.map { |i|  i = Stuff.new(number(i)).object_name }


 #=>
 object 1
 object 2
 object 3
 object 4
 object 5
 object 6
 object 7
```

However, I am trying to cluster them in groups of fives. How can I rearrange the code so that the output comes out in this manner (repetitive chains of one through five)...

```
 #=>
 object 1
 object 2
 object 3
 object 4
 object 5
 object 1
 object 2
 ...
```

I've tried certain loop variations but the outputs result in Array class objects, while I'm looking for the Fixnum class as the output.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the number with the group size and get the remainder. Increment since we have 0-indexed arrays in `Ruby`.

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

class Stuff
  attr_accessor :number
  def initialize(number, group=5)
    @number = (number % group) + 1
  end

  def object_name
    "object #{@number}"
  end
end

puts $array.map.with_index { |e, idx| Stuff.new(idx).object_name }
```

No need to create one more array to store indices.

Also, global variables should be used very carefully. [Looky-look here.](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html)

HTH

Comment: That worked out perfectly! But can you add on to the usage of global variables? What are the risks? From what I gather, you may overwrite other variables with the same values. But in this case, the global variable initiated is an array with other 600 elements, which are to be referenced throughout the code. What can go wrong? Just curious.

Comment: It's not a crime to use global variables. But from experience, as code size grows, it becomes difficult to isolate a bug caused by someone accidentally modifying the global variable or creating another global variable with the same name.